# WPF button click event is not fired in a new window running in a new STA thread

Tags: wpf, multithreading, click, sta

I want to run a progress window that has a button for cancelling a long save operation.

The main UI thread has the following code:

```
            WinBarProgress winBarProgress = null;

            Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
                {
                    winBarProgress = new WinBarProgress();
                    winBarProgress.Closed += (sender, e) => winBarProgress.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
                    winBarProgress.Show();
                    System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
                });
            thread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture;
            thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            thread.Start();
```

The winBarProgress window has a cancel button. The issue is that the cancel button is not firing the Click event.

Can anyone help me regarding this?